# How to unfold a python dictionary with lists as values into a list of key-value tuples with two elements?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have this kind of dictionary:

```
{'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

I'd like to know how to unfold it into a list of tuples like so:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6)]
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use list comprehension:

```
[(k,vi) for k,v in d.items() for vi in v]
```

With your sample input, this generates:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> [(k,vi) for k,v in d.items() for vi in v]
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6)]
```

Note that in most Python versions (not the recent one), dictionaries are unordered. Therefore the order of the *keys* can differ in the output (not the values *per* key). So `[('b', 4), ('b', 5), ('b', 6), ('a', 1), ('a', 2)]` is a possible result as well. You cannot solve that problem (with unfolding) since from the moment you construct such a dictionary, the order is lost.